# CSS padding top div modify the below div

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I've been working on an Angular plugin that uses a template. My goal is to add more `padding-top` to the section "loader-wrap", but when I do this, the second div called "message-wrap" is modified and moved as well.
I need add `padding-top: 100px` to 'loader-wrap' without moving down 'message-wrap' along with it. How do I fix this?

Basic Structure HTML

```
<div id="page-wrap">
  <section id="loader-wrap"></section>
  <section id="message-wrap"></section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
gp-splash-loader #page-wrap {
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@media ( max-height: 735px) {
  gp-splash-loader #page-wrap.opened{  
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
  };
}

gp-splash-loader #page-wrap.closed {
  opacity: 0;
}

gp-splash-loader #page-wrap.opened {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

gp-splash-loader #loader-wrap {
  width: 30%;
  height: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding-top: 50px; 
}
gp-splash-loader #message-wrap {
  min-width: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 30%;
  min-height: 30%;
}

  gp-splash-loader #header-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

check in codepen: http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/obdXEx

Comment: It's allways best if you create a working example, you have the option on the text editor..

Comment: Check my edited question.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because in order to be able to help you more, you need to tell us what you want it to look like exactly. adding padding will push down the loader, which ends up pushing down the message.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad  I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the deal. You can't move that loader down with padding, otherwise it will affect the message. you need a different solution. try the below html/css.

Basically I set it up so the loader and the message are in a div that will be centered. then inside of that centered div, you can do whatever you want. But the loader and message will be in the middle

if you want only the loader to be centered, then you can take the message out of the 'loader-message-box' div, and apply different styles to it. I'll work up a another fiddle for that solution

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/huf5zjkv/ - both message and loader are centered

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/huf5zjkv/1/ - this one will keep the message on the bottom

code:

html

```
<div class='loader-message-box'>
  <div class='loader-message'>
    <div class='loader'>

    </div>
    <div class='message'>
      Message
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='vertical-mid-hack'>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.loader-message-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.loader-message {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 -2px;
}
.vertical-mid-hack {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  height: 100%;
}
.loader {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: teal;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.message {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px: 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed any instance of `gp-splash-loader` from CSS. I don't know ng but I do know `gp-splash-loader` is not a valid selector. Other than that, the following CSS is the important part:

## CSS:

```
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: slateblue;
      text-align: center;
      top: 0;
      position: relative;
    }
    #loader-wrap {
      width: 30%;
      height: 70%;
      min-width: 300px;
      max-width: 600px;
      margin: 10px auto;
      padding-top: 100px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 10;
    }
   #message-wrap {
      min-width: 1px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 30%;
      min-height: 30%;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 11;
    }
```

- Added 50px `padding-top`
- Positioned both `relative` (and body as well)
- Made sure that one never touches the other by using different `z-index`

http://codepen.io/zer00ne/full/qbYMMQ/

BTW, if you want to adjust either section up or down, add `top` and a negative value if you want the section to go up and vice versa. ex.

```
  #message-wrap {
      min-width: 1px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 30%;
      min-height: 30%;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 11;
      top: -100px;
  }
```

That should place `#message-wrap` 100px higher.